# VASTU for newly constructed flat

Tags: tradition

can we keep 7 doors for eight entrances at newly constructed house.

we constructed a new house. there it has eight entrances...one main entrance, two for bed rooms ,two for bath rooms, one balcony and one for kitchen wash area.
my doubt is we have kitchen entrance, but can't keep there door as it is interfering with kitchen cupboards...is it okay as per vastu if we maintain 7 doors? 
pls let me know the solution.